# Can't use custom filter in a directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I've been stuck on this for quite a while and there's probably an easy fix but I'm pretty new to directives. I have a directive which is in an isolated scope. I have a filter that has been injected in the app but for some reason it won't work in the isolated scope of the directive. Here is my code for the directive (names have been abstracted)

```
var module = angular.module('SharedDirectives', []);

    module.directive('templ', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/templ.html',
            scope: {
                itemType: "@",
                items: "=items"
            }
        };
    });

    module.filter('formatAmount', function() {
        return function(amount, symbol, code) {
            if(amount != undefined && code != undefined) {
                var fixedAmount = (amount).toFixed(2);
                return symbol + fixedAmount + ' ' + code; 
            }
            else if(code == undefined && amount != undefined) {
                var fixedAmount = (amount).toFixed(2);
                return symbol + fixedAmount;
            }
        };
    });
```

And a snippet from my template:

```
{{10| formatAmount: '$' : 'USD'}}
```

Comment: The idiomatic way to test whether a variable is defined is: `typeof foo != 'undefined'`. Alternatively, you can use a function included in Angular: `angular.isDefined(foo)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that amount is a Number before using toFixed()

```
filterModule.filter('formatAmount', function() {
    return function(amount, symbol, code) {
        if(amount != undefined && code != undefined) {
            var fixedAmount = Number(amount).toFixed(2);
            return symbol + fixedAmount + ' ' + code; 
        }
        else if(code == undefined && amount != undefined) {
            var fixedAmount = Number(amount).toFixed(2);
            return symbol + fixedAmount;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: That is strange. I should also say that my error message is: Can't interpolate: {{item["amount"] | formatAmount: item["currency_symbol"]}} {{item["currency_code"]}}
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Yes, the array is well defined. Even without the array putting static numbers the same error is returned in the browser. If I remove the scope from the directive (therein making it not isolated) the filter works. I think this is definitely a scope issue.

Comment: The items are an array of two items each with the properties expected. I should also mention that the directive and the filter are in two separate modules. Maybe I need to inject the SharedFilters module into the SharedDirectives module?

Comment: Oh wow. That solved the issue. I can't believe I spent so long on this. Thanks user3413129. Seriously life saver man.